# Computing Partial Derivatives of a Function wrt Another Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have two functions $P_1,Q_1$ which are both depending on the variables $r_{T_m}, r_{i_f}$, which are theirselves functions of $T_m, mi_f$. I am interested in computing the Jacobian

$$\frac{\partial (P_1,Q_1)}{\partial(r_{T_m}^2,r_{i_f}^2)}\Bigg|_{r_{Tm}=f(T_m) \\ r_{i_f}=g(mi_f)}.$$

To do that, I first define the function

```
powerD[f_, x_^(k_.)] := powerD[f, {x^k, 1}];
powerD[f_, {x_^(k_.), 0}] := f;
powerD[f_, vars__] := Fold[powerD, f, {vars}];
powerD[f_, {x_^(k_.), n_Integer?Positive}] := Det[Append[Table[(j!/i!) Binomial[k i, j] x^(k i - j), {i, n - 1}, {j, n}], Table[D[f, {x, j}], {j, n}]]]/(k x^(k - 1))^Binomial[n + 1, 2];
```

(because I want to compute the derivative wrt the power of $r_{T_m}, r_{mi_f}$), then I want to substitute $r_{T_m}=f(T_m)$ and $r_{i_f}=g(mi_f)$. However, something in the code fails at this point. I think it is because instead of first computing the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial r^2_{T_m}}$ etc. and then substituting $r_{T_m}=f(T_m)$, it tries to compute $\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial f^2(T_m)}$.

I attach here the code ($P_1,Q_1$ are actually functions of other parameters too, but I substitute these other parameters with the needed numerical values before computing the Jacobian).

The function $P_1(r_{T_m},mi_f)$ is given by

```
P1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif]=-1.12469*10^-8 (1.71055*10^13 - 112.657 rif^2 + 112.657 rTm^2 - 9.60432*10^-10 (-5.66361*10^20 - 3.52759*10^9 rif^2 + 3.52759*10^9 rTm^2 + Sqrt[(5.66361*10^20 + 3.52759*10^9 rif^2 - 3.52759*10^9 rTm^2)^2 - 3.26026*10^16 (3.2715*10^26 - 3.83021*10^15 rif^2 + 12691.7 rif^4 - 4.07533*10^15 rTm^2 - 25383.3 rif^2 rTm^2 + 12691.7 rTm^4)]))
```

and the function $Q_1(r_{T_m},mi_f)$ is given by

```
Q1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif]=6.13447*10^-17 (-5.66361*10^20 - 3.52759*10^9 rif^2 + 3.52759*10^9 rTm^2 + Sqrt[(5.66361*10^20 + 3.52759*10^9 rif^2 - 3.52759*10^9 rTm^2)^2 - 3.26026*10^16 (3.2715*10^26 - 3.83021*10^15 rif^2 + 12691.7 rif^4 - 4.07533*10^15 rTm^2 - 25383.3 rif^2 rTm^2 + 12691.7 rTm^4)])
```

I compute the elements of the (2x2) Jacobian matrix as

```
J11[rTm_, rif_] := FullSimplify[powerD[P1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif], rTm^2]]
J12[rTm_, rif_] := FullSimplify[powerD[P1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif], rif^2]]
J21[rTm_, rif_] := FullSimplify[powerD[Q1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif], rTm^2]]
J22[rTm_, rif_] := FullSimplify[powerD[Q1[230 1.73, 0.2, 0.0072, 100 3.14, rTm, rif], rif^2]]
```

and then I build the full Jacobian matrix as

```
J[rTm_, rif_] := {{J11[rTm, rif], J12[rTm, rif]}, {J21[rTm, rif],J22[rTm, rif]}}
```

Up to here everything is okay, but then when I substitute
$$r_{T_m}=f(T_m)=\sqrt\frac{(230\cdot1.73)^4 + 4\cdot(230\cdot1.73)^2\cdot0.2\cdot100\cdot3.14\cdot Tm}{4\cdot(0.2)^2}$$

and

$$r_{i_f}=g(mi_f)=\sqrt\frac{230\cdot1.73\cdot mif\cdot100\cdot3.14 }{(0.2)^2 + (100\cdot3.14\cdot 0.0072)^2}$$

with the command

```
J[Sqrt[((230 1.73)^4 + 4 (230 1.73)^2 0.2 100 3.14 Tm)/(4 (0.2)^2)], Sqrt[((230 1.73) mif 100 3.14)/((0.2)^2 + (100 3.14 0.0072)^2)]]
```

I get the errors
"6.25 (2.50666*10^10+3.97711*10^7 Tm) is not a valid variable",
"24254.6mif is not a valid variable."

I have just started today using the software, so I am sure it is a pretty easy mistake to be solved, maybe I should assign the values differently to the various Jacobian elements $J_{i,j}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Q[r1, r2]` and `P[r1, r2]` (I am using simplified notation).
The Jacobian is defined by:

```
D[{Q[r1, r2], P[r1, r2]}, {{r1, r2}}]
```

[image]

However, you want derivatives wrt. `r1^2` and `r2^2`. Toward this aim we introduce new variables :

```
w1 = r1^2;
w2 = r2^2;
```

and `Q` and `P` are written: `Q[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]]` and  `P[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]]`.

With this we now get the Jacobian:

```
D[{Q[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]], P[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]]}, {{w1, w2}}]
```

[image]

Or in the old coordinates, where I assume that r1>0 and r2>0:

```
Simplify[D[{Q[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]], 
    P[Sqrt[w1], Sqrt[w2]]}, {{w1, w2}}] /. {w1 -> r1^2, 
   w2 -> r2^2}, {r1 > 0, r2 > 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight! So you suggestion is to just use your last piece of code to compute the full Jacobian J?

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem using the "substitution method" you showed above, very nice. I basically replaced the last line of the code I posted in the question with
```
FullSimplify[J[RTm, Rif] /. {RTm -> ((230 1.73)^4 +  4 (230 1.73)^2 0.2 100 3.14 Tm)/(4 (0.2)^2), Rif -> ((230 1.73) mif 100 3.14 )/((0.2)^2 + (100 3.14 0.0072)^2)}]
```